# Thread 1: "-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the \"Bf3-ih-lsC-view-YnG-aC-da7\" nib but didn't get a UITableView."

Tags: swift5

```
import UIKit
 
@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        Model.shared.loadXMLFile(date: nil)
        Model.shared.parseXML()
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
   
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `UITableViewController` in your storyboard, its main view must be a `UITableView`.  This error often happens when some other controller type is changed to a `UITableViewController` but with its old main view still in place.